# Angular JS: using $interval to refresh service data

Tags: angularjs, service

I am facing following problem:

In my AngularJS application, I have service, which includes data and a function, which refreshes them

```
angular.module('testService', ['ui.router'])
.factory('testService', function($http) {

  var service = {};

  var _baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/';
  service.orders = {created: 0, approved: 0};

  /*
  * get number of unprocessed orders
  */

  service.updateNOrders = function(){
    var tableName = 'orders?stats=true';
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: _baseUrl + tableName,
    }).success(function(data){
      service.orders = data;
      console.log(data);
      return;
    }).error(function(err){
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    })
  }
});
```

I can inject this service to i.e. directive and call the function `updateNOrders` to update the data from the directive.

What I want, though, is for service to call this function every `n` seconds.

The service is shared in several directives and instead of every directive, taking care of updating the data, I would like the service to do it itself.

I have tried comething like:

```
angular.module('testService', ['ui.router'])
.factory('testService', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $interval) {

  $interval(console.log('test'),1000);

  /*
  rest of the code
  */


});
```

but that does not work.

So - Is it possible to call the function `updateNOrders` inside `testService` every minute or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating service with side effect is the bad idea. Better off create service with method which sets your interval with callback. Then you can inject your service in run callback (run calls callback only once):

```js
angular.module('testService', ['ui.router'])
.factory('testService', ['$interval', function($interval) {

  var service = {};

  service.doPeriodicAjaxRequest = doPeriodicAjaxRequest;

  function doPeriodicAjaxRequest() {
    $interval(yourCode, ...);
  }

  return service;

}]);
```

Then:

```js
angular.module('', [])
  .run(['testService', function (testService) {
    testService.doPeriodicAjaxRequest();
  }]);
```

Comment: this is great. I added some checking, so this function does not get call multiple times, and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you call the service function from controller in certain interval of time.

```
 $interval(testService.functionName,1000);
```

Comment: I dont use controllers in the application, only directives